# ASP.NET: The difference between page.Session and HttpContext.Current.Session

Tags: asp.net, session

Is there any difference between page.Session["name"] and HttpContext.Current.Session["name"]?

Comment: No difference..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference. **Page.Session** returns pointer to **HttpContext.Current.Session** object.